# return a range of values from an array in underscore.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have an array with the following data

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

I am looking for a method in underscore.js or backbone.js in which I can return the elements with a specified range. for ex:

```
filter(2,5) should return  [3,4,5,6]
```

which is the 2nd to 5th index elements in the array. Any pointers for me ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Javascript Array should be defined like below,

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]; //not inside {}
```

And then you can use array native [**slice**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method to get elements from a specific position

```
a.slice(2, 6) //should return 3,4,5,6
```

**Edit:**

> I very well know that the functionality is available in JScript. I was asking if its available in backbone or underscore. You are asking like why would you want an ice cube instead of water because ice will turn to water eventually.

Underscore js **do not** have function like `slice` as it is already available in native js.

Comment: anything from underscore or backbone ?

Comment: Why would you need this functionality to come from underscore or backbone if it's available natively in Javascript?  After all, if you're using underscore or backbone, you're using Javascript.

Comment: @TitoCheriachan That water and ice comparison is not entirely same. Anyways underscore/backbone js do not have function like slice as it is already available in native js. There is no reason to implement feature like slice without proposing any improvements to the existing feature.

Comment: It's not quite the same.  To use your own metaphore, ice can be removed from a glass of water whereas water is inseparable from water, meaning if you ever wanted to run some kind of diagnostic on those methods, you could always inject your own code into those methods, whereas you cannot with with native code.

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1:**

Switch to Lodash. (https://lodash.com/)

*Note: dangerous step, you will never go back.*

**Step 2:**

Use the `_.slice` function like this:

`_.slice(a, 2, 5)`